# PHP crawler in redirected URL

Tags: php, redirect, web-crawler, goutte

I call a URL and after two seconds it open a random URL.
I want content of that second URL.
I try Goutte and CURL but it did not work properly maybe because of that delay in redirect.
anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you dd the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

To follow standard HTTP redirects with cURL, set the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

[See docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

If the redirect is done via non-standard way, i.e. JavaScript, this will not work.

Comment: Please provide more details on how the page does the redirect, i.e. the first URL